# If given a Substring, is it possible to access the underlying complete String on which it is based?

Tags: swift, range, substring, swift4

Say I have the following code...

```
let x = "ABCDE"
// 'x' is a String

var y = x[1...3]
// 'y' is a Substring that equals "BCD"
```

If you only have access to `y`, is it possible to access `x`, or specifically parts of `x` which are outside the range of `y`? (i.e. can you access 'A' or 'E', or grow the range of `y`?)

Comment: Note that this would not be the proper usage of `Substring`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's what Apple says:

> Important
>
> Don’t store substrings longer than you need them to perform a specific
>   operation. A substring holds a reference to the entire storage of the
>   string it comes from, not just to the portion it presents, even when
>   there is no other reference to the original string. Storing substrings
>   may, therefore, prolong the lifetime of string data that is no longer
>   otherwise accessible, which can appear to be memory leakage.

Now I find their use of the word "otherwise" in the last sentence rather interesting.  It seems to me to keep the door open on this question - could a substring be manipulated to be expanded to include memory on either side that we know still exists as part of the original string?

So here's what I'd think is a fair test:

```
let x = "ABCDEFGH"

let substr = x.prefix(3)
var substrIndex = substr.startIndex
substr.formIndex(&substrIndex, offsetBy: 4)  // offset beyond the substring
let prefix = substr.prefix(through:substrIndex)
print(prefix)
```

So what'cha think that would print?
Actually we never get to the print. We get a runtime fatal error instead.

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Operation results in an invalid index
```

BTW, even trying the following results in an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash:

```
let x = "ABCDEFGH"

var substr = x.prefix(3)
withUnsafePointer(to: &substr)
    { substrPointer in
        let z = substrPointer.advanced(by: 3)
        print(z.pointee)
    }
```

So I don't think there's a way to get to the rest of the string if you just have a substring... from within Substring or String classes anyhow, or even dealing with unsafe pointers.  I'm sure there's a way using direct memory access, for Apple claims the rest of the String's memory is there... but you'd probably have to fall back to C or C++.

Comment: Darn! Was hoping I'd be able to 'peer into' the next item.  I was trying to use a simple 'for' loop over a string's characters, but if a certain character comes after the current one, I had to do something different. I guess I'll have to manually manage the indexes and substrings myself as with them I can easily 'peer into' the next, and just increase the index accordingly.

Comment: @MarqueIV Sounds like you're writing your parser. Why not use an existing parsing library?

Comment: Too simple of a need to warrant one. I was updating old code which looped through the characters of a string, each which represent control steps. The spec changed to allow specific trailing characters to be 'modifiers' to the previous command. (i.e. 'A>B' is two commands, 'A' and 'B' and '>' is a modifier on 'A') I was hoping I could just 'peer ahead', but since I can't, and you can't skip ahead in a 'for' loop anyway (needed for modifiers), the proper change is to us a 'while loop' based on the position index. That solves all issues. This q was simply testing the bounds of the Swift language.